# Autopan option for popup for mapbox leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I am using mapbox js version 3.1.1 and using leaflet, There will be many markers in map and each marker is attached with a popup. By default autopanning option is enabled for popups, When the marker is at top corner of the page, The opened popup is not fully displayed. Based on the change log of leaflet plugin(v1.3.1) the popup panning issue has been fixed, But the mapbox js using leaflet version "1.0.2", What do I have to do to have these plugin changes?